openai error handler for Image Processing in whatsapp app
I encountered a problem in my code, when I run the code to process the images sent to my WhatsApp by OpenAI, it can't read the image, can you help me?
private async handleMediaMessage(message: Message) {
    const media = await message.downloadMedia();
    if (media) {
      try {
      
        const imageBuffer = Buffer.from(media.data, 'base64'); 
        const processedImage = await this.imageProcessor.processImage(imageBuffer); 

        const response = await this.getOpenAIResponse(`Describe this image: ${processedImage}`);
        message.reply(response);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error processing image:', error);
        message.reply('There was an error processing the image.');
      }
    }
}

Well, when an image was sent to my WhatsApp, it recognized its type, such as JPG, but it could not process it.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
